Why is there a save icon and a number next to my git branch in PowerShell oh-my-posh?
I am new to using PowerShell to do my git commands and on some of my repositories, I see the following symbol:

what does this symbol mean?
I looked up symbols but did not find much.

@FrankThomas that is what I thought too but it says nothing to commit, working tree clean

@FrankThomas tried that and the number didn’t change. Git diff shows local and remote are the same

so the symbols are not universal, but determined by your choosen theme. what theme are you using in oh-my-posh?

@FrankThomas I am currently using 1_shell but it’s shows the same for others as well

@FrankThomas it’s also different for other repos

I have to assume its one of these items, but thats the best I can offer: "template": " {{ .UpstreamIcon }}{{ .HEAD }}{{if .BranchStatus }} {{ .BranchStatus }}{{ end }}{{ if .Working.Changed }} \uf044 {{ .Working.String }}{{ end }}{{ if and (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }} |{{ end }}{{ if .Staging.Changed }} \uf046 {{ .Staging.String }}{{ end }}{{ if gt .StashCount 0 }} \ueb4b {{ .StashCount }}{{ end }} ", do you have any stashes?

@FrankThomas That was it! thank you!

You can check default oh-my-posh themes definitions here. They are just JSON files with definitions of settings and segments - reusable types of thematic blocks.
In this case you wanted to look for:
"type": "git"

which is a definition of a git segment.
Each segment uses a template, which can be either default or overwritten. This theme overrides it:
"template": " {{ .UpstreamIcon }}{{ .HEAD }}{{if .BranchStatus }} {{ .BranchStatus }}{{ end }}{{ if .Working.Changed }} \uf044 {{ .Working.String }}{{ end }}{{ if and (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }} |{{ end }}{{ if .Staging.Changed }} \uf046 {{ .Staging.String }}{{ end }}{{ if gt .StashCount 0 }} \ueb4b {{ .StashCount }}{{ end }} ",

Then you can use the Unicode codepoint to find out about a specific icon. OMP themes usually make use of Nerd Font characters. On that website you can look for any codepoint in the found template.
In this case you can see the one you were looking for is \ueb4b at the end of template:

so as @FrankThomas said in the comment, it displays number of stashes if it's higher than 0, which can be found in git documentation linked above.
